# Echo statement not showing in bash output

Tags: bash, terminal, psql

I wrote a script to automatically insert data from a csv file into two separate SQL tables.
The script is working but it is not printing the echo statements after the validity of a test.

```
echo $($PSQL "TRUNCATE TABLE games, teams")

cat games.csv | while IFS=',' read YEAR ROUND WINNER OPPONENT WINNER_G OPPONENT_G
do
    TEAMS=$($PSQL "SELECT name FROM teams WHERE name='$WINNER'")
    if [[ $WINNER != "winner" ]]
      then
      if [[ -z $TEAMS ]]
        then
        INSERT_TEAM=$($PSQL "INSERT INTO teams(name) VALUES('$WINNER')")
        if [[ INSERT_TEAM == "INSERT 0 1" ]]
        then
        echo Inserted into teams, $WINNER
        fi
      fi
    fi

    TEAMS2=$($PSQL "SELECT name FROM teams WHERE name='$OPPONENT'")
    if [[ $OPPONENT != "opponent" ]]
      then
      if [[ -z $TEAMS2 ]]
        then
        INSERT_TEAM2=$($PSQL "INSERT INTO teams(name) VALUES('$OPPONENT')")
        if [[ INSERT_TEAM2 == "INSERT 0 1" ]]
        then
        echo Inserted into teams, $OPPONENT
        fi
      fi
    fi
done
```

after iseerting teams, its supposed to print the team names inserted
for example "Inserted into teams, Brazil"

Comment: That's a [useless `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) and an [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).

Comment: You could do all of it using PSQL query language only.

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". Also please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and then fix your variable names as whatever problem you're having could just be due to you overwriting some environment variable settings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Shellcheck finds the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[ INSERT_TEAM == "INSERT 0 1" ]]` will always be false, because the string *INSERT_TEAM* is not equal to the string *INSERT 0 1*. You want to compare the content of the **variable** INSERT_TEAM to the string *INSERT 0 1*. Therefore you want to do a

`[[ $INSERT_TEAM == "INSERT 0 1" ]]`

instead. Note that this compares for an exact match. If you want to test that the string is a *substring*  of what is stored in the variable `INSERT_TEAM`, the comparison becomes

`[[ $INSERT_TEAM == *"INSERT 0 1"* ]]`

Comment: Thank you very much. this worked excellently.